# Why does intergral of a double power only work when there is an another x in the intergral

Tags: integration

why does [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSiut.gif) work and give a nice answer but [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJxgg.gif) gives a weird answer.

For context, I was asked [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aa8H.png) question and didn't understand how the answer was explained because I don't understand why how the above pics work.

[image]

Comment: Its because the first one is of the form $\int e^tdt$ while the other isn't

Comment: +1 re thoughtful and supplied background (re "I was asked...").  Minor complaint: On mathSE, please use mathJax to format your math, re https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

You can substitute $u=x^9$ then $du=9x^8dx$.
So that the integral becomes:
$$I=\int 15 x^{17}e^{x^9}dx=\dfrac {5}{3}\int ue^udu$$
Integrate by part.

Comment: +1 elegance....

Comment: Thanh you @user2661923 ...